# How to update text based on ListWheelScrollView

Tags: firebase, flutter-web

I am trying to cycle through an array of texts based on `ListWheelScrollView` using `onSelectedItemChanged`, but the text does not update, however the variable change does appear in the console

I am extending `StatefulWidget` too

Here is my `ListWheelScrollView`:

```
ListWheelScrollView(
                    onSelectedItemChanged: (i) {
                      setState(() {
                        prompt = promptList[i];
                        devtools.log(prompt);
                      });
                    },
...
```

and my `Text` widget looks like this:

```
Text("$prompt",
                    key: const Key("textKey"),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 250))),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I defined my variable `prompt` inside my `build` widget instead of the class itself, I'll leave this in case someone else makes the same mistake